# Apache RewriteRule to redirect all files requests to php handler

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to get a rewrite rule that would allow for any files requested in the following form:

```
/assets/files/uploads/306/This-is-an-awesome-file.jpg
```

to be handled by file.php, and any files requested such as

```
/assets/files/uploads/306.jpg
```

to not be matched and just return the file as normal

The path: /assets/files/uploads/ is guaranteed to be there, the fourth token is guaranteed to be either 'number'.'extension' or 'number'/'title'.'extension'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more general regex, with / and . escaped

```
^\/assets\/files\/uploads\/[0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$
```

The + means the character right before must appear at least once. [something] specifies a valid range of characters, so [a-z] means any lower case letter, and [abc] means only allow a b c. Thus, here we require that there be a number (at least one digit), then a slash, then a filename (I assumed alphanumerics and underscore for the filename, but you can include other things in [a-zA-Z0-9_] that are legal), followed by a . and a file extension.

^ denotes the start of a line, $ denotes the end. You may or may not need these.

Not being familiar with Apache RewriteRule, I don't know what effects that has on the regex.

Comment: Thank you sir. Put me on the right track. Final solution was a bit different. I'm editing your answer to reflect it. Thanks again.